The cookie with "wp_ga4_customerId" cookieName couldn't be sent. Please try again later
We are getting this exception for last two days but did not found any clue why the cookie unable to sent.

[2024-09-04 03:27:19] main.CRITICAL: The cookie with
"wp_ga4_customerId" cookieName couldn't be sent. Please try again
later.
{"report_id":"9507bd6b3afed07d3a86096bc10ef7b61d1f2884c76e945e609b17cd87ca4837","exception":"[object]
(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException(code: 0):
The cookie with "wp_ga4_customerId" cookieName couldn't be sent.
Please try again later. at
lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php:163)"}
[]

